# Cannot create symbolic variable n row 1 column in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

In MATLAB, I want to create symbolic variable n row 1 column as: [y1;y2;...;yn].
Then I use the code:

```
y=sym('y',[n,1]);
```

Now I use n=49, then the output is

```
[49 Element Column Vector]
[Data Type: Anything]
[Storage: rectangular]
[Order: Fortran_order]
```

Why I can't create the symbolic vector [y1;y2;...;y49] in MATLAB? What is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: It seems like you did create that vector. What is the issue?

Comment: I mean why the output cannot be
```y1
y2
...
y50``` 
(column vector)